# Updating a windows service project to .NET 5, System.Configuration.Installer, how can I add it to my project?

Tags: windows, .net-5

Now that .NET 5 has been released I thought I'd look into upgrading some of the applications we have, and in one of them we have a windows service.

It seems that some of the namespaces that we rely on, one of them being `System.Configuration.Install`, doesn't exist in .NET 5 out of the box. I'm assuming there is a trick to it, like adding support for Windows forms does it with the `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`, or that there is a nuget package I can add that will provide the missing bits but after trying for about an hour to find the right thing I thought I'd ask here instead.

Is there a way to bring that namespace and other related bits into a .NET 5 project? If so, how?

And yes, I have set target framework to `net5.0-windows` first.

Comment: I suppose the actual question is how to install the application as a Windows Service, not use that specific class. Is self-installation an actual requirement? Otherwise you could use `sc create workertest binPath=` to install the service. [.NET Core Workers as Windows Services](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services/) shows how to create a worker project that is hosted as a service. Service hosting and lifetime management are provided by the `UseServiceBaseLifetime()` call, not the worker template itself

Comment: [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) goes into more detail. The first half of the article is about service hosting and applies to non-ASP.NET Core applications as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will check it out, but that webpage details the new way to write worker services, if that is the only way to go we will have to postpone the upgrade a bit because that is a completely different way of approaching service applications. We're also using other dependency injection frameworks and from my experience it isn't easy bridging those two bits together with the new hosting frameworks.

Comment: And no, self-installation isn't really 100% required, but again it will require multiple changes, both to the project and to the pipeline that deploys it as it already is using the self-installation part. I will hold off on doing anything in the hopes that a bigger rewrite isn't necessary.

Comment: Inside Visual Studio, if I place the cursor on `Installer` in the line `internal class WindowsServiceInstaller : Installer`, and hit Alt+Enter, I get  a suggestion for "using System.Configuration.Install; (from System.Configuration.Install)", but selecting this pops up a progress window that never completes, so it seems Visual Studio is trying to help me bring in the right bits but then ... doesn't.

Comment: as [written in docs, the API is full .net framework and Mono only](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Configuration.Install), but not .net core. .net 5 = .net core 5

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you should probably migrate to another deployment technology. Few people use those classes as a) they only made the easy things easier and b) current deployment requirements go way beyond a simple MSI installer. A Powershell DSC configuration can be used to specify and deploy services to multiple target machines for example. For desktop apps, NSIS can be easier to write and still produces proper MSI packages.

Answer (score 5):

There are no plans to port this to .NET Core. There's [a Github issue discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29643) about this. The source is getting released to Microsoft/References [this very month](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/pull/145) but the PR wasn't merged yet. Some people have decompiled the classes and created packages from it, like [Core.System.Configuration.Install](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Core.System.Configuration.Install/)

Few people would recognize that namespace as the classes used to "simplify" Windows Installer actions much less use it. I think last time I used it was 2004? 2005? I've used proper installers generators after that and lately, declarative configuration management scripts like Powershell DSC or Puppet.

It's probably easier to write the PowershellDSC script that defines the services, counters, event logs to install than try to create the equivalent MSI actions. Never mind deploying to more than one servers.

Another option may be to wait for a week or two until the source code is merged into ReferenceSource or wait until someone works out the kinks and packages it.

Comment: I agree completely, and I'll accept this answer but the issue is that we already have this project, running fine, on .NET Framework, but if the upgrade to run .NET 5 is going to entail a lot more than just switching the TFM for this project we will be forced to postpone it due to time constraints. Unfortunately it uses a lot of other common libraries that are in use by other applications that *can* be upgraded, so most likely we will have to keep status quo for now and a bit into next year, to avoid upsetting other time schedules.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen or you can wait for a week or two until the source is released to references and use it. Or a month until someone works out the kinks and packages